# return value from reference of address in C++

Tags: c++, void-pointers

Sorry if my wording is incorrect but here is the code:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char bSaveRestore;
    unsigned short wPresetId;
}
uvcx_ucam_preset_t;
...
uvcx_ucam_preset_t data;
data.wPresetId = 0;
data.bSaveRestore = 0;  
setProperty(&data);
...
setProperty(void *data ...)
{
  //How to access wPresetId and bSaveRestore here...
  // The next line is where I'm using it.
  hr = ksControl->KsProperty((PKSPROPERTY)&extProp, sizeof(extProp), data, dataLen, &bytesReturned);}
  /* Here is from hsproxy.h
   STDMETHOD(KsProperty)(
        THIS_
        _In_reads_bytes_(PropertyLength) PKSPROPERTY Property,
        _In_ ULONG PropertyLength,
        _Inout_updates_bytes_(DataLength) LPVOID PropertyData,
        _In_ ULONG DataLength,
        _Inout_opt_ ULONG* BytesReturned
  */
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to figure out why my camera is rebooting on the line mentioned and other structures seem ok. I just can't see anything from data, but if I break before the call, I can see data is ok. I've tried created a variable void *test = &data just before the call and I have the same problem trying to access data.

I'm unable to figure out how to deal with data inside setProperty. From my playing around in debug:

```
data is the address.
&data is the address of the address.
*data gives an error "expression must be a point to a complete object type"
```

Comment: Sounds like you've forward-declared `uvcx_ucam_preset_t` and haven't provided a full definition at the point you're trying to use it.

Comment: Can you provide an appropriate example?

Comment: Why is `setProperty` taking `void*` as parameter? Why not `uvcx_ucam_preset_t*`?

Comment: KsProperty require data to be LPVOID

Comment: @JohnSmith You need to perform explicit conversion, .e.g. `static_cast<uvcx_ucam_preset_t*>(data)->wPresetId...`.

Comment: @songyuanyao can you please provide corrected example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an object of type `uvcx_ucam_preset_t`, `&data` returns the address of `data`, i.e. a pointer with type `uvcx_ucam_preset_t*`. `setProperty` is taking `void*` as parameter, when passing `&data` the pointer converts to `void*` implicitly.

In `setProperty`, if you want to access data member `wPresetId`  or `bSaveRestore` you need to convert the pointer back explicitly. e.g.

```
setProperty(void *data)
{
    uvcx_ucam_preset_t* p = static_cast<uvcx_ucam_preset_t*>(data);
    p->bSaveRestore = ...;
    p->wPresetId = ...;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try that, but it brings up another question. Since   hr = ksControl->KsProperty((PKSPROPERTY)&extProp, sizeof(extProp), data, dataLen, &bytesReturned); is a built in function, how does it know what structure data will be since it's an LPVOID?

Comment: I accepted this answer on the basis of the question. I believe I have found that my code is not correct for what is to happen before the setProperty line.

Comment: @JohnSmith I suppose it performs conversion too; based on some kind of conventions.